# Poodle SSL 3.0 issue, no update for Windows Phone?

Tags: security

Hi just checked my 1320 need a fix for [Poodle](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.nl/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html). Is an update available?

I used https://www.poodletest.com/ and found that IE is vulnerable to SSL 3.0 attacks. I think a fix is much needed as mobiles devices are used on public networks and more prone to this hack.

Comment: I've been disabling SSLv3 for the last 5 or 6 years because of all the problems (SSLV3 problems have been well know since at least 2006, and some even prior). Its sad that these phone manufacturers still allow SSLv3, and worse that they don't give the user a choice.

Comment: It also affects the email client, with no support for TLS (only SSLv4) for IMAP and SMTP servers

Answer (score 1):

There are registry values which will disable SSL3 (or other SSL/TLS versions). See [this thread on XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development/poodle-ssl-vulnerability-secure-windows-t2906203) for the change to make (in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` registry key, create/set the `SecureProtocols` value to DWORD `2688` or 0xA80 if your editor app wants hex).

In order to do this, you will need a working registry editor app. There is one available for Lumias (though you'll need an SD card in order to install it) here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development/xap-vcreg-lumia-reg-editor-live-interop-t3135326

I like to use this kind of thing as an example of why Microsoft's policy of locking users out of the ability to control their own devices is a bad and harmful policy. I had my phone protected against POODLE within a few days of its publication. Meanwhile, those who won't or cant interop-unlock their phones are stuck with the vulnerability until Microsoft releases a patch (apparently 8.1u2 makes you safe, but most phones never got that one).